# JTextPane, Document insertString , javax.swing.text.BadLocationException

Tags: java, exception, jtextpane

I have this class extending from `JTextPane`

```
public class MyClass extends JTextPane {

      public SimpleAttributeSet getAttributeSet(JTextPane textPane) {
        SimpleAttributeSet attrSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        if (getBackground() != null) {
          StyleConstants.setBackground(attrSet, getBackground());
        } else {
          StyleConstants.setBackground(attrSet, textPane.getBackground());
        }
        if (getForeground() != null) {
          StyleConstants.setForeground(attrSet, getForeground());
        } else {
          StyleConstants.setForeground(attrSet, textPane.getForeground());
        }
        Font font;
        if (getFont() != null) {
          font = getFont();
        } else {
          font = textPane.getFont();
        }
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attrSet, font.getFamily());
        StyleConstants.setItalic(attrSet, font.isItalic());
        StyleConstants.setBold(attrSet, font.isBold());
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrSet, font.getSize());
        return attrSet;
      }

....
....

}
```

Running code like:

```
Document doc = this.getStyledDocument();
try {
  doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Some not null String", this.getAttributeSet(this));
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger("BadLocationException:" + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Sometimes I got:

**`javax.swing.text.BadLocationException`**

I don't understand the reason, beacuse the Object(`this`) is not null, and the String always will be inserted at valid position...

What would be the reason?
I'm using wrong Class?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please add a description of the difficulty you are having.

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem . So you need a frame with a JTextPane and some code to insert text in the Document. It should be about 20 lines of code to demonstrate your stated problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert text with the same attributes as the text at the end of the  Document, then you can do something like:

```
int pos = doc.getLength();
Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(pos - 1);
doc.insertString(pos, "more green text", element.getAttributes());
```

Comment: Then if the attributes are different this solution would not work?

Comment: What is your requirement??? I made my best guess at what your code is attempting to do. If you want the attributes to be different then you should be passing the attributes as a parameter along with the text. Without a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem I can't help further.